# Kubernetes: port-forward for service object getting timed out

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am trying to `port-forward` to k8s **service** object which is getting timed out. I am using the k8s cluster in my **docker desktop**.

Is that some additional setting required for this?

```
$ kubectl get service
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          205d
springboot-ms   LoadBalancer   10.106.71.156   127.0.0.240   8080:30742/TCP   18m
```

Here is the port-forward:

```
$ kubectl port-forward service/springboot-ms 8080:8080
error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

However, if I perform the port-forward to my deployment object, it works perfectly.

```
$ kubectl port-forward deployment/springboot-ms 8080:8080
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Handling connection for 8080
```

Comment: HI, it seems you already have the service of type loadbalancer which is assigned an IP. You can directly access the application using curl http://<external-ip>:<port>. From kubernetes docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/

Comment: I followed the instruction mentioned here -https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/kubernetes-metal-lb-for-docker-for-mac-windows-in-10-minutes-23e22f54d1c8
The direct requests doesn't work for some reason and hence I am trying to port-forward

Comment: ok.. but there is no mention of port forward in link you shared. It just mentions "Even though your address will come back as 127.0.0.240, it will all be accessible through your local host address. On Mac this will only be routable by visiting either 127.0.0.1:8080 or localhost:8080. On Windows you should be able to access Nginx on 127.0.0.240:8080 as well as 127.0.0.1:8080."

Comment: Yes, but you see comments section, it didn't work for people and after port-forward to service object it worked.
I still can do port-forward to deployment but it looses the load balancer feature

Comment: Are you using `minikube`? With docker desktop it's much easier to enable built-in kubernetes and all loadbalancer services will be exposed on localhost. Try it and let me know if this helps. I also will explain in the answer about `kubectl porf-forward service`

Comment: I am not using minikube, instead I am using the docker-desktop built-in k8s.
Even I tried the build-in load balancer of docker it didn't worked then I tried metallb. Perhaps, in both approaches the issue may be the same.

Comment: Please provide more details. Why it didn't work when you try use build-in load balancer of docker. What error did you get? I did steps from instruction you sent in previous comments and it worked for me with simple application. As you can read [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15180#issuecomment-410798267) port-forwarding doesn't work with loadbalancer

Comment: @RadekW - The issue is the same. I get the same error as mentioned in the post. Initially I thought the problem with default docker-desktop LB and then switched to metallb. The issue is the same.
Do you mean the port forward never works for load-balancer? But it worked for others in the reference post which I provided in my comment.
As you mentioned, it work for you without the port-forward. Even it is also not the case for me. When it didn't work directly then I tried port-forward.
In short, nothing is working for me

Comment: Could you reproduce what you said it is working for others from this article you provided?

Comment: I am trying exactly the same steps with one difference is that the image. Instead of nginx, I am using my own image.
All the output which is stated in the article is the same... The only issue is the response that I am not able to get after the loadbalancer created

Comment: Could you try reproduce with nginx image and checks if it works? We will know if the issue is with loadbalancer